# Error converting data type varchar to float LARAVEL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type varchar to float.
```

When returning this raw DB query?

```
DB::table('ORD_HEADER')
                ->join('ORD_DETAIL','ORD_DETAIL.OD_ORDER_NUMBER','=','ORD_HEADER.OH_ORDER_NUMBER')
                ->join('STK_STOCK','STK_STOCK.STKCODE','=','ORD_DETAIL.OD_STOCK_CODE')
                ->join('SL_ACCOUNTS','SL_ACCOUNTS.CU_ACC_CODE','=','ORD_HEADER.OH_ORDER_NUMBER')
                ->join('SL_ACCOUNTS2','SL_ACCOUNTS2.CUCODE2','=','SL_ACCOUNTS.CU_ACC_CODE')
                ->select('CUNAME')
                ->where('OH_PRIORITY',0)
                ->where('STK_SORT_KEY','PRODUCT')
                ->where('CU_USRCHAR1','<>','')
                ->groupBy('CUNAME')
                ->get();
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Really not enough to go on.  My guess would be one of your joins is trying to compare a float and a varchar but without the table structures, that'd be hard to tell.

Comment: what's your database schema? I would say that 'PRODUCT' causes problems